# How to make a custom DialogPreference using Android x?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-preferences, preferences

With **Android x** the **DialogPreference** is moved to **DialogPreferenceCompat** . As there are many ways to make a **custom layout** in the **Preference** settings .

I am looking for more **clean and better way** to make a **custom layout** that when clicked opens the **Custom Number Picker Dialog Box**. I would like to make a custom layout  with a button .

The issue right now I am facing is there is **no onCreateDialog** override method in **DialogPreference** and I am not sure how to make the changes. It looks like due to **DialogPreferenceCompat** used in android x my most of the code is broken.

How can I make the correct code changes? There are many ways to write the Custom Preference layout but I don't know which one is good one.

[image]